# Can we get $\|A^\dagger x-B^{-1}x\|_2\leq \epsilon \|B^{-1}x\|_2$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

In the question:

the  $A\in R^{d\times d}$ is positive **semi-definite**, $B\in R^{d\times d}$ is positive **definite**,  $x\in R^d$ is a vector, and $\epsilon$ is a variable that may depend on $A$, $B$ and $x$.

The column space of $A$ belongs to that of $B$.

$A^\dagger$ is the Moore–Penrose pseudo inverse of $A$, and $B^{-1}$ is the inverse of $B$.

$\|\cdot\|_2$ is a spectral norm for a matrix or a $l_2$ norm for a vector.

Comment: Does positive (semi)-definite imply symmetric in this context? Does $\dagger$ denote some kind of pseudo-inverse?

Comment: You mean that $\epsilon$ may depend on $A$ and $B$, not $A$, $B$ and $x$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes they are symmetric.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich just for example, $\epsilon=\|A^\dagger\|_2^2\|B^{-1}\|_2$.

Comment: Huh? That doesn't depend on $x$; what's your point? If $\epsilon$ actually is allowed to depend on $x$ then the problem is utterly trivial: Let $\epsilon=\|A^\dagger x-B^{-1}x\|_2/\|B^{-1}x\|_2$.

Answer (score 2):

$B$ is invertible, so it contains the column space of *any* matrix of the same shape.

You're looking for an upper bound for 
$$
\frac{\|(A^\dagger - B^{-1})x\|}{\|B^{-1}x\|}
$$
which, if we set $x = By$, is the same as finding an upper bound for
$$
\frac{\|(A^\dagger B - I)y\|}{\|y\|}
$$
Which is to say that we're finding a bound for $\|A^\dagger B - I\|$.  We can say much about this.  The best we could do is say that 
$$
\|A^\dagger B - I\| \leq \|A^\dagger B\| + \|I\| \leq \|A^\dagger\|\cdot \|B\| + \|I\| = \|A^\dagger\|\cdot \|B\| + 1
$$